# Joomla 3 addStyleSheet, change "rel" attribute to "stylesheet/less"

Tags: php, css, joomla, less

I am developing template and I am working on .less files with client side JavaScript compiler. This compiler needs `rel="stylesheet/less"` attribute to understand what to compile.

so I have this code:

```
$doc->addStyleSheet( $this->baseurl.'/templates/'.$this->template.'/css/style.less', 'text/css' );
```

that generates

```
<link type="text/css" href="/templates/sss/css/style.less" rel="stylesheet">
```

so how to change my php addStyleSheet code to generate this output?

```
<link type="text/css" href="/templates/sss/css/style.less" rel="stylesheet/less">
```

Comment: In fact, this is a problem of the less compiler. The code behind the `href` is LESS, not CSS, so the correct notation is `type="text/less"`, which *can* be handled by the Joomla API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla doesn't support `rel="stylesheet/less"` when using `$doc->addStyleSheet();`. There are obviously ways around it but it would involve hacking into the core Joomla code which I don't even want to get into.

The only solution for the time being till they add this feature in is to use:

```
<link type="text/css" href="/templates/sss/css/style.less" rel="stylesheet/less">
```

You could also use `$doc->addCustomTag();` but this is pretty much the same.